# How can I determine the WBXML value for an XML tag in ActiveSync for Exchange?

Tags: java, android, exchange-server, activesync

I'm extending an Android email client, and would like to add conversation threading to it for an Exchange ActiveSync account. It appears that the client sends requests using wbxml.

To add some of the Conversation specific tags (for example, [ConversationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee124266%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)) to my request, I need to know the wbxml value of the tag.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a wbxml tag for ActiveSync can be found [on MSDN in the Code Pages section for Active Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219143%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

The ConversationMode tag value can be [found on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218904%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), and it's value is 0x27

Comment: for quick, local testing of wbxml creation/parsing, you can look at the following javascript library from Mozilla: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/jswbxml